# I am extending my header and footer but when I pass data in footer it is visible only at home page not on other pages

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, jinja2

I am extending my header and footer but when I pass data in footer it is visible only at home page not on other pages.
I know that I have to pass that data on every pages but I am looking for  a easy solution
example:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from footer.models import Footer

   def home(request):
       contact_info = Footer.objects.all()
       return render(request,'frontend/index.html', {'contact_info':contact_info})
```

**Index.html**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-1">
                <div class="gtco-widget">
                    <h3>Get In Touch</h3>
                    <ul class="gtco-quick-contact">

                        {% if contact_info %}
                        {% for i in contact_info %}
                        <li><a href="tel:{{ i.phone }}"><i class="icon-phone"></i>{{ i.phone}}</a></li>

                        
                        <li><a href="mailto:{{ i.email }}"><i class="icon-mail2"></i>{{ i.email }}</a></li>


                        <li><a href="http://maps.google.com/?q={{ i.location }}"><i class="ti-location-pin"></i>{{ i.location }}</a></li>
                        {% endfor %}

                        {% endif %}

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

At Contact Page:
[image: screeshot]

At Index Page:
[image: screeshot2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need your data in every pages, then you can use context processor.

In you app folder, create context_processor.py

In **context_processor.py:**

```
def context_processor(request):
    context = {}
    context['data'] = 'Some data'
    return context
```

In **settings.py:**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...,
        'OPTIONS': {
            ...,
            'app_name.context_processor.context_processor'
        }
    }
]
```

In your **templates**. In your case, you can use in your footer.html

```
{{data}}
```

FYI: You don't need to work with your views also.

Comment: Hemant Yadav(Delhi India): Yes, I used this and it's working fine for me. As I think this is not for only head or footer even you can pass you, models, here and you may call any where in your project templates.

Comment: Yes, depends upon requirements.

Answer (score 2):

**context_processor.py**

```
from designzoned.models import ServicesModel
def context_processor(request):
   context = {}
   context['service_list'] = ServicesModel.objects.all()
   return context
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            # In below line you have to write like this
            'designzoned.context_processor.context_processor',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

**header.html**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   {% for service in service_list %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'services_detail' service.slug %}">{{ 
       service.name }}</a></li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```