# I want to pass variable from base template ( basic.html which have navigation and footer) to child template(index.html)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I was trying to pass my unicategory variable which I want to show in my navigation of all the templates which I extend (`basic.html` which contains footer and header) and `index.html` which is my home page.

so the idea is this I have passed the variable in unicategory function and render it in basic.html to show all unique categories in my navigation bar of.
i have extended `basic.html` in `index.html` and when i use loop to show the unicategory variable its does not working

basic.html

```
<nav>`{% for i in unicategory%}    
         <li><a href="{% url 'Stores:categories' i.scategory %}">{{i.scategory}}<span> ( {{i.posts_count}} ) </span></a></li>
      {%endfor%}`
</nav>
```

basic views

```
def basic(request):
    stores = stores_model.objects.all()  
    unicategory = stores_model.objects.values('scategory').distinct().order_by().annotate(posts_count=Count('scategory'))
    context = {'stores':stores , 'unicategory':unicategory }

    return render(request,'Home/basic.html',context)
```

i want to extend this template in index.html as header and i want to show this category on index page also.

index.html

```
    {% extends 'Home/basic.html'%}
    {% block body %}------some front page code-----{% endblock %}
```

index.views

```
    stores = stores_model.objects.all()
    context = {'stores':stores }
    return render(request,'Home/index.html',context)
```

Comment: hey, please show me your `urls.py ` file thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am extending my header and footer but when i pass data in footer it is visible only at home page not on other pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65068310/i-am-extending-my-header-and-footer-but-when-i-pass-data-in-footer-it-is-visible)